# Rails Debug method in GitLab pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, gitlab-ci

I am contributing to the GitLab repo of my team, and my merge request is failing in pipeline's *test_job* phase, while passing the tests locally. Hence I need to debug in pipeline method I wrote. Locally I can do it easily in Rails console(or logs) by putting `p` or `Rails.logger` where I want. I can also inspect variables from test files to output them to pipeline like this:

```
# test/helpers/some_helper_test.rb
p var_to_check
test 'something' do
    assert_equal(my_method(var_to_check), 10)
end
```

but `p` and `Rails.logger` (while being in my_method)are not outputting internals of `my_method` in pipeline while in *test_job* phase.

Since my tests are failing only in pipeline, how can I inspect the internals of `my_method` method to output some variables to pipeline?